# C pointers Output

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, output

Can someone please help me understand why I'm receiving this Output?
I'm getting confused with the first printf: f[2]=3
The second printf I have no problem.
And the whole third printf is confusing for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DIM 8

int*func(int*,int);

int k = 10;

void main(void)
{
  int i;
  int k = 11;
  int f[DIM];
  int*p1 = f+1;
  int**p2 = &p1;
  int*p3;
  char* zf[]={"text0", "text1", "text2"};

  for(i=0; i<DIM; i++) 
    f[i] = i % DIM + 1;

  printf("a) i=%d, *f=%d, f[2]=%d, *(p1+5) =%d\n", i, *f, f[2], *(p1+5));
  printf("b) k=%d, zf[1]=%s, **zf=%s, **p2=%d\n", k, zf[1], *zf, **p2);

  p3 = func(f, k);
  p1 = p1 + 3;

  printf("c) k=%d, *p3=%d, f[7]=%c, *p1=%d\n", k, *p3, f[7], *p1);
}


int* func (int ff[])
{
   int* p4 = (int*) malloc (sizeof(int));
   *p4 = ff[3];
   k = k - 3;
   ff[k] = 65;
   return p4;
}
```

Output:

```
a) i=8, *f=1, f[2]=3, *(p1+5) = 7
b) k=11, zf[1]=text1, **zf=text0, **p2=2
c) k=11, *p3=4, f[7]=A, *p1=5
```

Comment: Terribru - a mess of single-letter var names.

Answer (score 0):

Discussed the relevant ones :-

```
int*p1 = f+1;
```

`f` decays into pointer to first element (`int*`). `f+1` is nothing but `&f[1]` or address of `f[1]`. Remember, pointer arithmetic uses units of the size of whatever type it points to. Here `+1` meant adding `sizeof(int)` to the `f`.

`*f` in the first printf dereferences that pointer (decayed pointer). As it was a pointer to the first element, `*f` is `f[0]`.

`p1+5` is moving `5*sizeof int` bytes from `f+1` which is `&f[6]`. So `*(p1+5)` is `f[6]`.

`%c` prints the character whose ASCII value is stored in `f[7]` and in the called function we made `f[7]=65`, the ASCII value of character `A` is `65`.

`p1=p1+3` points to `f[4]` with the same logic as before - it prints `5` and that's why.

Dynamically allocated memory which has lifetime beyond the scope of the function - you returned it and the value that is stored there is printed.(`*p3`). The value assigned to allocated memory is the element at index `3` of the array `f`. You have passed it to the function `func`.